# Are there any third-party libraries to do cool view transitions in iPhone OS?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, core-animation

I don't really like that flip-transition. It's boring. I'd like to see something cool, like water effect, fog, or whatever. Is there something available or do I have to (re)invent the wheel for that?

Answer (score 17):

The animation types available via `[CATransition animation]` are:

- `kCATransitionFade`
- `kCATransitionPush`
- `kCATransitionMoveIn`
- `kCATransitionReveal`
- `@"suckEffect"`
- `@"spewEffect"`
- `@"genieEffect"`
- `@"unGenieEffect"`
- `@"rippleEffect"`
- `@"twist"`
- `@"tubey"`
- `@"swirl"`
- `@"charminUltra"`
- `@"zoomyIn"`
- `@"zoomyOut"`

The transition types available via `[UIView setAnimationTransition:forView:cache:]` are:

- `UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft`
- `UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight`
- `UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp`
- `UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown`

Comment: the first list is hidden API, right? What's apple gonna do when I use that? I'm pretty sure I've seen once an App using the rippleEffect. Exactly the same one from the foto app when watching the slide show (old iPod touch).

Comment: The transitions defined by kCATransition* (and their subtypes) are public, the others are hidden. If you don't want to use private APIs you can try animating the transform property of your CALayer to imitate some of the hidden transitions.

Comment: Do you have experience using the hidden API transitions? Did Apple still accept them? I wonder if they would even be able to know that you use hidden api...

Comment: It's hit and miss from what I understand. I haven't used any private CATransitions in any of my apps, but there are definitely some up on the store that use them. It's a relatively safe private API to use because if you use a transition type that is unavailable, UIKit fails gracefully by showing a fade transition instead of crashing.

Comment: Is Charmin Ultra a big (but soft and gentle) swiping movement?

Comment: Most of them are not supported since 3.x - http://www.iphonedevwiki.net/index.php?title=UIViewAnimationState

Comment: Most of these are private and cannot be used - they'll default to fade

Answer (score -1):

The iPhone SDK comes with a whole bunch of built in animations.  rpetrich listed some of them and I do believe that there are more.

For example using the UINavigationController class provides stock animation which, while simple, is quite effective.

Comment: Animations that are built in to the SDK.