# Different types of CATransition types available in iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone

Do anyone knows the link to the different types of name for available CATransition.

Like ripple,swift....

I want to know all the available names.

Answer (score 43):

These are the types that are available:

```
kCATransitionFade
kCATransitionMoveIn
kCATransitionPush
kCATransitionReveal
@"cameraIris"
@"cameraIrisHollowOpen"
@"cameraIrisHollowClose"
@"cube"
@"alignedCube"
@"flip"
@"alignedFlip"
@"oglFlip"
@"rotate"
@"pageCurl"
@"pageUnCurl"
@"rippleEffect"
@"suckEffect"
```

Subtypes that are available are:

```
kCATransitionFromRight
kCATransitionFromLeft
kCATransitionFromTop
kCATransitionFromBottom
```

The ones in the link @rkb posted are mostly private and cannot be used.

Comment: Is there any documentation about these "additional" transitions. I can only find these 4 in the [iOS Dev center](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATransition_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004507) Is there any reference by in the Apple Docs?

Comment: Most of the ones you've listed a private, and not supported. You can probably get away with using them because the automated code checking Apple does doesn't check for transition type strings, but if a human reviewer figures out what you are doing then your app will be rejected. Apple only lists kCATransitionFade, kCATransitionMoveIn, kCATransitionPush and kCATransitionReveal in the docs, so those are the only officially supported ones.

Answer (score 4):

[Are there any third-party libraries to do cool view transitions in iPhone OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825826/are-there-any-third-party-libraries-to-do-cool-view-transitions-in-iphone-os)

Here are the available types.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the documentation for CATransition? They're all listed at the bottom (there's a link to the list in the documentation for `-type` and `-subType`). There is no "ripple" or "swift." Where are you getting those from?

Comment: Yeah these are the types available. They are in string format.