# iOS 7 create flip animation like rotate animation in native camera app

Tags: ios, core-animation, avfoundation, ios-camera

I am working with AVFoundation for create iOS app with custom camera.
My problem is camera rotate, the preview layer with be changed front/back camera, how to produce animation like native camera app.
Flip Animation ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
animation.duration = .5f;
animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
animation.type = @"oglFlip";
if (captureDevice.position == AVCaptureDevicePositionFront) {
    animation.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
}
else if(captureDevice.position == AVCaptureDevicePositionBack){
    animation.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;
}
[capturePreviewLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
```

Comment: Perhaps you should explain the value of the type property and why you should set that. It's not listed in the headers so maybe you should also explain where you got it from.

Comment: Please see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224580/different-types-of-catransition-types-available-in-iphone-sdk

Comment: I have another issue with this animation. Flip animation works well, but in Camera App, the animation contains Blur overlay screen and then Flip screen. Can you help me make that animation ? I am focusing in native camera app iOS 7/ iphone 5s. Thanks so much

Comment: Hi,Iker. Do you mean add a blur effect before animation start, after completing the animation, remove it, right?

Comment: yeah, Vincent. like native camera app of iPhone 5s. Can you help me a solution for this ? Thanks,

Comment: This is really easy. you can just added a blur layer or view to you `capturePreviewLayer`, then add the following code below your animation code ``` [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
        [layer removeFromSuperlayer];
    }];```   Here is a blur effect library:https://github.com/JagCesar/iOS-blur

Comment: Thanks for your guide, Vincent. Will try and let you know the result.

Comment: You have nailed it!

Comment: Outstanding ,, !